# Open source editor for Microsoft Windows that handles read-eval-print loop

Tags: text-editor, ide, programming, editor

I would like to teach [Standard ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) for my students.

I have a console version of the [PolyML](http://polyml.org) Standard ML compiler that has a read-eval-print loop.

What editor would you recommend that

- is open source
- runs on Microsoft Windows
- is able to handle a compiler that has a read-eval-print loop
- preferrably, it has an installation-less version so that I could copy some files onto a network drive and the students could use promptly

Emacs comes to my mind but my students are not hardcore geeks so a friendlier one would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/)** (open source, free).

It has all req's which you wrote. For Standard ML support, need to write simple Python plugin, guys can help you to write it at editor's forum.
Plugin can show dialog, or can use Console panel (ctrl+tilde).